# What can increase natural reach for a druid?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, druid, reach, trip

I was wondering which items and feats would help my druid (level 15) increase his tripping ability. I plan on doing a reach trip build in wild shape and tree shape form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Feats

[Lunge](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/lunge-combat-final/) and [Monkey Lunge](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/monkey-lunge-combat/) are the easiest way to increase your reach.

For tripping, we have several good options:

- [Improved Trip](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/improved-trip-combat-final/) and [Greater Trip](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/greater-trip-combat-final/) are both solid choices for any build focused on trip;
- [Fury's Call](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/fury-s-fall-combat/) will allow you to add your Dex bonus to your CMB;
- [Tanden Trip](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/tandem-trip-combat-teamwork/) is also an interesting option if you plan on tripping with an ally;
- [Wolf Trip](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/wolf-trip-wolf-style/) will allow you to pick where the target will fall prone;
- [Drag Down](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/drag-down-combat/) will grant a free trip attempt when you are tripped.
- [Tripping Strike](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/tripping-strike-combat/) will allow you to make a trip attempt whenever you score a critical hit.
- [Riptide Attack](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/riptide-attack-combat/) might be interesting if you desire to drag enemies aswell.

### Items

Both [Longarm Bracers](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/a-b/longarm-bracers/) and [Pliant Gloves](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/e-g/gloves-pliant/) do talk about **arms** when increasing your reach, so depending on what you agree with your GM, your tree forms may or may not have arms *per se*.

The [Gauntlets of Skilled Maneuvers](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/e-g/gauntlets-of-the-skilled-maneuver/) will grant +2 on the chosen combat maneuver, a [Brown Thorny Ioun Stone](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/h-l/ioun-stones/ioun-stone-thorny/) will grant +2 *competence* bonus on trips. Other than that, most trip enhancing magic items are magic weapons or weapon ehnacements.

However, a [Wild](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-armor/magic-armor-and-shield-special-abilities/wild/) [Adhesive](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-armor/magic-armor-and-shield-special-abilities/adhesive/) Armor will grant a +2 enhancement bonus on trip checks when using natural attacks. The *Wild* enchantment is required or otherwise your armor bonuses will cease to function while [polymorphed](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Transmutation-Polymorph).

Comment: Right and how about for trip? Improved trip, greater trip, fury's fall, are there any others? I only know of the three. Are there ant traits that will help tripping specifically?

Comment: It's worth noting that Lunge/Monkey Lunge only apply during your turn, not for Threatening opponents during their turns.